# Chrome Debugging Protocol: HeapProfiler.getHeapSnapshot Ignores Callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

I'm working on a testing suite (implemented as a Chrome extension) that programmatically takes and analyzes heap snapshots with Chrome/Chromium's remote debugging protocol. Because `Profiler.*` doesn't seem to be part of the public protocol, I'm using [this page](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/Inspector.json) for reference.

Right now, I'm able to take a heap snapshot by calling `HeapProfiler.takeHeapSnapshot` like in the snippet below.  However, when I try calling `HeapProfiler.getHeapSnapshot`, my callback is completely ignored.

```
var debuggerId = {tabId: sender.tab.id};
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggerId, "1.0", function() {
    var listener = function(source, method, params) {
        if(source.tabId === debuggerId.tabId) {
            if(method === "HeapProfiler.addProfileHeader") {
                var uid = params.header.uid;
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggerId, "HeapProfiler.getHeapSnapshot", { uid: uid }, function() {
                    console.log("I never get called!");
                });
                chrome.debugger.onEvent.removeListener(listener);
            }
        }
    };
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(listener);
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggerId, "HeapProfiler.takeHeapSnapshot", { reportProgress: false }, function() {
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError) { console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError); }
    });
});
```

Comment: Marvelous...just what I was looking for. Too bad this isn't  documented with the rest of the debugging protocol.

Comment: Example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455644/programatically-get-memory-usage-in-chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in DevTools. I've filled [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260749) in chrome bug tracker.

Fortunately there is a workaround.
You have to enable Debugger agent before getting the snapshot.

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId,"Debugger.enable", { }, function() { });
```

Three other commands were also affected by this bug.

```
Profiler.start
Profiler.stop
Profiler.getCPUProfile
```