# How to know each TAB data usage in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to know the data/bandwidth usage of each tab opened ?. Is there any API for this ?.

I want to make a chrome extension based on this. Any pointers would be helpful.

What I exactly want to do is:
Show a small counter beside the tab name/page title.
The counter should update itself every 5-10 seconds. 
It should show the amount of data/bandwidth consumed by the tab.

chrome://net-internals/#export.

This shows the overall bandwidth usage once the event starts ? Can I get this tab wise ?. Any API for this ?.

Is this possible in Chrome ?. I found this in Firefox as an add-on(tab-data).
Link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-data/

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes) says that you can use `chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab(integer tabId, function callback)` to get the process id of the tab, and then `getProcessInfo − chrome.processes.getProcessInfo(integer or array of integer processIds, boolean includeMemory, function callback)` to get the memory usage and other stuff.
Look at the link for more detailed info

Here there's a question on this topic: [Programmatically get memory usage in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455644/programatically-get-memory-usage-in-chrome)

Comment: Big Red Warning regarding this API: **"This API is experimental. It is only available to Chrome users on the dev channel."**

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question. Sorry for misleading you by saying memory usage