# Delegation and data attributes vs closure in event handler performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, binding

What is more performant way to assign events?
Not taking code quality into account since it is sort of opinion-based thing.

### Delegated binding + data attributes

```js
var o = [{ key: "1", value: "one" }, { key: "2", value: "two" }, { key: "3", value: "three" }];
var $container = $("#container");

$.each(o, function() {
  $("<button/>").text(this.key).data("value", this.value).appendTo($container);
});

$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  console.log($(this).data("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

### Single direct bindings + closured value

```js
var o = [{ key: "1", value: "one" }, { key: "2", value: "two" }, { key: "3", value: "three" }];
var $container = $("#container");

$.each(o, function() {
  var x = this;

  $("<button/>")
    .text(x.key)
    .click(function() {
      console.log(x.value);
    })
    .appendTo($container);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

If we use the first approach, then we win some performance because of the delegated event handler, but lose some because we are creating a jQuery object and reading data attributes.

Will the second approach take up more memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is more performant?

I created [this test](https://jsperf.com/button-click-handlers/1) on jsperf.com. I tested three different browsers and in each case the delegate approach proved to allow more operations per second:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Approach     | Chrome | FF     | MS Edge |
--------------------------------------------
| Delegate     | 1650   | 1612   | 611     |
| non-Bindings | 1623   |  558   | 320     |
--------------------------------------------
```

Thus the delegate approach is *more performant*.

> Will the second approach take more memory?

After reading some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18455644/1575353), I reached the latest version of the Google Chrome guide [Fix Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/). On that page there is a [section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#monitor_memory_use_in_realtime_with_the_chrome_task_manager) which describes how to monitor memory specific to javascript within Chrome tabs. I saved each of the code snippets as a separate HTML page (i.e. *buttonClickDelegate.html* and *buttonClicks.html*, respectively) and opened both in a separate tab. As is observable in the screenshot below, the delegate approach used less memory.

[image]

However I compared with Firefox's memory usage, following the techniques in [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Memory/Basic_operations#Opening_the_Memory_tool). After opening the single page with the delegate approach, the memory started at 1.17 MB and went up to 1.59 MB (after clicking each button and then taking a final snapshot, with *Record callstacks* enabled). With the non-delegate approach, the memory started at 1.07 MB and went up to 1.24 MB (after clicking each button and then taking a final snapshot, with *Record callstacks* enabled).

So it seems firefox is using more memory in the delegate approach, unless that is just the entire application memory and not specific to the JavaScript code.

[image: ffMemoryComparison]